# Psensor only showing graph

Tags: gui, psensor

After restarting my computer, Psensor only shows the graph. The list of sensors has disappeared. Tried to stretch the window with no success. The sensors show up in the taskbar menu though. Running Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Hey, Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by unchecking "Restore window position and size" in Psensor preferences >> Startup.